# Player pauses for a second before moving (on some devices)

Tags: unity-game-engine

i have a 2d platformer with a player that moves. It works perfect in unity and i packaged it and downloaded the apk on my galaxy s7 which also works perfect.

I then tested it in my local supermarkets tablet display and on both tablets i tried, if i touched left, it would pause for a second, then move left.

The animated enemies, spinning coins and physics was working fine so there wasnt that type of lag, just a pause when moving which makes me think the code i have to move is wrong. The tablets looked fairly high spec too.

Here is how i move the player, i call this in the update function:

```
List<FingerTouch> currentTouches = new List<FingerTouch>();

public class FingerTouch 
{
    public int id;
    public float beganXPos;

    public FingerTouch (int fingerId, float fingerBegan)
    {
        this.id = fingerId;
        this.beganXPos = fingerBegan;
    }
}

if (!disableMovment)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < Input.touchCount; i++)
            {
                if (Input.GetTouch(i).phase == TouchPhase.Began && !EventSystem.current.IsPointerOverGameObject(Input.GetTouch(0).fingerId))
                {
                    float xPos = Input.GetTouch(i).position.x;

                    if(xPos < Screen.width / 5)
                    {
                        playerLeft = true;
                    } else if (xPos > ((Screen.width / 5) * 4))
                    {
                        playerRight = true;
                    } else
                    {
                        playerUp = true;
                    }

                    int fingerId = Input.GetTouch(i).fingerId;

                    currentTouches.Add(new FingerTouch(fingerId, xPos));
                } else if (Input.GetTouch(i).phase == TouchPhase.Ended)
                {
                    if (currentTouches.Count != 0)
                    {
                        for (int j = 0; j < currentTouches.Count; j++)
                        {
                            FingerTouch currentTouch = currentTouches[j];

                            if (Input.GetTouch(i).fingerId == currentTouch.id || currentTouches.Count == 1)
                            {
                                if (currentTouches[j].beganXPos < Screen.width / 5)
                                {
                                    playerLeft = false;
                                }
                                else if (currentTouches[j].beganXPos > ((Screen.width / 5) * 4))
                                {
                                    playerRight = false;
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    playerUp = false;
                                }

                                currentTouches.RemoveAt(j);
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    } else {
                        playerUp = false;
                        playerRight = false;
                        playerLeft = false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

It looks a little over the top but it basicily divides the screen into 3 sections 20/60/20 which move left right jump. When the user touches, it stores that touch and when its released, its removed.

This allows multi touch (jumping and moving) while also preventing jumping, sliding ur finger to the right and removing it and being in an unlimited jumping state as you didnt remove your finger in the middle.

Then after that it moves the player like this:

```
    if (hitLeftWall && playerLeft)
    {
        playerBody.velocity = new Vector2(0, playerBody.velocity.y);
    }
```

Is there anything here that would cause the player to pause before moving? Should this be in fixed update as the player has a rigidbody? Im new to unity so im not sure on the proper way to do things yet.

Comment: Could you add more details, because given the current information is hard determine what's causing the issue.

Comment: thats all there is really, its just the player moving. The player is a sprite. If theres nothing in this code that would cause a pause before moving im thinking it might just bet that the devices were slow.

Comment: After reading, it seems other people are facing input lag on some android devices so the problem probably lies with unity and how it handles android device touches themselves